# Jquery In GSP page gives Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) error

Tags: jquery, grails

In my gsp page i am trying to create link dynamically using jquery during the page load..

```
            <r:script>

            function loadEmailButtons(mailTask,rowIndx,trainingIds){
            alert(rowIndx);
                $.each(mailTask, function(index, value) {
                    if(value ==0){
                        $(".table2 tr:eq("+(rowIndx)+")").append("<td width='5%' ><span><g:link action='mail' params='[mailType:'Training_Information']'  controller='mailDraft'  id='1'>Info</g:link></span></td>");
                    }
                });
            }


            $(document).ready(function(){   

                var mailDraftReminderInstance = ${mailDraftReminderInstance};
                loadEmailButtons(mailDraftReminderInstance, 2,trainingInstanceIds);
            });
 </r:script>
```

but im getting error:

in the console i can see

```
     function loadEmailButtons(mailTask,rowIndx,trainingIds){
        $.each(mailTask, function(index, value) {
            if(value ==0){
                $(".table2 tr:eq("+(rowIndx)+")").append("<td width='5%' ><span><a href="/opal/mailDraft/mail/1?mailType=Training_Information">Info</a></span></td>");

            }
        });
    }
```

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )** near href

whats wrong here... is there any other way to create dynamic link which produces above url?

Comment: it's because of closing quote after `href=`

Answer (score 1):

The `<g:link>` tag is generating an anchor that uses double quotes around its attribute values. Instead of

```
<g:link action='mail' params='[mailType:'Training_Information']'  controller='mailDraft'  id='1'>Info</g:link>
```

Try this:

```
<a href='${g.createLink(action:'mail', params:[mailType:'Training_Information'], controller:'mailDraft', id:'1').encodeAsJavaScript()}'>Info</a>
```

The `encodeAsJavaScript` will escape things like quotes in a form suitable for use in a JS string literal, and you should use it on any generated value that you want to include in a JavaScript string. See the [section on codecs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/security.html#codecs) in the Grails user guide for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your double quotes around the `href` attribute are the problem. Use single quotes like in the `width` attribute, then it should work:

```
$(".table2 tr:eq("+(rowIndx)+")").append("<td width='5%' ><span><a href='/opal/mailDraft/mail/1?mailType=Training_Information'>Info</a></span></td>");
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(".table2 tr:eq("+(rowIndx)+")").append("<td width='5%' ><span><a href="${createLink(action:'mail', params:'[mailType:'Training_Information']', controller:'mailDraft', id:'1')}">Info</a></span></td>");
```